# Custom Form Validation for AngularJS- how to check for specific words in a textarea the angular way

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am creating an app using AngularJS where a user is given a list of words he must include in a form he will submit. For example, if the list of words is "Shnur" and "Bdur" the form will be valid if the user enters: "Shnur and Bdur were walking down the street when..."
but not valid if the write "Shnur went off in search of some grub." because only one of the two required words was included. I would also like to be able to dynamically change the color of the word/phrases  once the user enters it.

Currently, I have this in my controller:

```
    function ($scope, $routeParams, $location, Global, Submissions, Phrases){
          $scope.Global = Global;
          $scope.phrases = _(Phrases).shuffle().slice(0, 5);
```

I am injecting the Phrases service and am randomly selecting a few phrases the user must incorporate into his submission. Based on my research, it seems like the next step will be to write a directive which does the custom form validation, but there seems to be so many ways to do that and I'm really having trouble getting a clear sense of the structure of the directive that will be appropriate for this specific case. (This is my first real angular app)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure it's the best solution, but here is what I would have done for something like this : http://jsfiddle.net/DotDotDot/K2S4v/

As you thought, I made a directive which is kind of complicated, so I will try to explain it here :

The structure of the directive is something like :

1. Passing the list of word to compare in argument
2. Adding an input field to the template
3. Listening to modification in this field
4. Checking new words, and counting the number of matching ones
5. Displaying and stuff like this

   ```
   .directive('validate', function(){
   return {
       restrict:'A',
       template:see below,
       replace:false,
   ```

the template looks like this for the example, but actually it could be empty, it was a lot easier to use this for the display
    `<p><span ng-bind-html-unsafe="theDisplayedText"></span><br/>{{count}} words corresponding</p>`

Then, the important part, I used the compile function, to add the input field, and then to specify the behavior in the postLink function

Adding the field (this could be done directly in the template too, not the main point)

```
compile:function(elt,attr){ 
        var inp=new angular.element('<input>')
        inp.attr('type','text')
        inp.attr('ng-model','theText');
        inp.attr('ng-change','changed()');
        elt.append(inp)
```

then to specify how the directive has to react, the linking function :

```
       return {
        pre: function preLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) { 

        },
        post: function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) { 
            scope.count=0;
            var copyOfWords= new Array(iAttrs['list'])//the list to compare with

            scope.changed=function(){
                var alreadyIn=Array();
                scope.theDisplayedText=angular.copy(scope.theText);
                var sliced=scope.theText.split(" ");//we get each word
                scope.count=0
                for(var i=0;i<sliced.length;i++){
                        if(sliced[i].length>3 && copyOfWords.indexOf(sliced[i])!=-1 && alreadyIn.indexOf(sliced[i])==-1)//the word exists and isn't counted yet
                        {
                            scope.count+=1//incrementing the counter
                            alreadyIn.push(sliced[i])//avoiding doubles
                            sliced[i]="<span class='hi'>"+sliced[i]+"</span>"//display in red
                        }
                }
                scope.theDisplayedText=sliced.join(" ");
            }            
        }
      }
```

The function is really naive and not really optimized, this might be the part you will have to change, but it works for the example. It's quite simple, you take the whole text, split it in words, then compare them with the list of words in argument. It has some issues (it appears that `indexOf()` on string arrays return also a result for every substring, so if you begin to type a word, it will be counted) but it's only for the example, in your application, you may have to perform better checks, or whatever you want (it's your app :) )

I hope this will help you in your application, if you have some issues concerning directives, there are many information in this site : http://amitgharat.wordpress.com/2013/06/08/the-hitchhikers-guide-to-the-directive/

Have fun =)

Comment: Just a note, this will only work for space separated words.  It will not match words that have punctuation that come immediate after it.